# HTML Form Submit Button Not Passing HTTP_Referrer Info

Tags: google-analytics, form-submit, referrer

I was looking into my site's Google analytics code and realized that a a lot of pages that show up when my site visitor clicks on an html form submit button () are being logged as direct visitors.

Since these pages do not show up unless the visitor clicks on a form submit button, it is likely that the reason why these pages show up as the landing page for direct visit is because the referrer details are not being tracked.

Could someone help me out on how this can be fixed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can't even begin to tell you why the referrer details are not being tracked, without you posting or pointing to any code.. but in general you can specify the referring URL with [_setReferrerOverride()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setReferrerOverride)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the general way we are showcasing the form submit button:


`code`
<input type="submit" class="class-name" value="Value name" name="" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'a', 'b', 'c']">